# Trying to save and access an ArrayList Android in different activities

Tags: java, android, arraylist, data-storage

I am a beginner android developer and I am looking for some help with saving files. On the developer documentation from Google, they state to use Internal storage to save files. 
My goal is to currently create an arraylist that can be saved and accessed as necessary.

Currently, I have an activity where the user can input data into fields and it will create a new object with that data. I am trying to get that data added to an arraylist and then saved. However, I need the arraylist to be checked in the MainActivity which is accessed when the application is first made. The main activity needs to check for whether an ArrayList already exists or whether a new one needs to be created. Then that arraylist needs to be sent(through Intents, already understand that part) to the rest of the activities which all perform actions on the arraylist, and then send it back to the mainactivity where it is saved.

Any help that can be provided will be infinitely appreciated. I am sorry if there is a lack of clarity, and I will do my best to clarify. Any tips on improving my android skills would also be well appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "save", what kind of persistence are you talking? Memory? Internal storage? How long do you want to keep your data?

Comment: I would like to keep the data almost permanently, basically until the user deletes the file. I would like to be able to edit the arraylist regularly.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is load the file into your ArrayList. You can do that with an AsyncTask for example. More information on this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Second, if your ArrayList is big, I would suggest to extend the Application class and save your instance of ArrayList there instead of sending it via an Intent. That way every Activity (and other components of your app) can access it. When you send data through an intent, the date is marshaled / unmarshaled which can take a lot of CPU time and stutter your activity transitions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by loading the file into the arraylist. I am trying to store the arraylist as a file. Essentially making an arraylist of object PEOPLE and then storing that arraylist for access later. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried to store/load the file?

Comment: Sorry but I have not written much code. I am still trying to figure out the order in which to put the file output and input and still trying to understand how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it depend on how you wanna save those datas. Is it on a file (saved on memory card) but can be deleted by the user.

If you don't want allow the user to access to those datas you have : 
- [SQLite database](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
- [Shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

If the arraylist doesn't need to be stored for futher uses, you also can use a singleton class (wich is very easy to use).

```
public class Singleton {
private static Singleton mInstance = null;

private ArrayList<Integer> mArray;

private Singleton(){
mArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public static Singleton getInstance(){
if(mInstance == null)
{
mInstance = new Singleton();
}
return mInstance;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getArray(){
return this.mArray;
}

public void setArray(ArrayList<Integer> value){
mArray = value;
}

public void addValue(Integer value){
mArray.add(value);
}
}
```

Or use extra intent like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,name.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putIntegerArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<Integer> value);
i.putExtra(String name,b);
startActivity(i);

Bundle b = getIntent().getExtra().putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name);
```

Comment: I do want the user to be able to edit the arraylist from within the application only. Also I need the data to be stored and accessed every time the app is opened. Like I need to access that one arraylist in every activity on every part of the app.

Comment: So use SQLite database. ArrayList is just an object to manipule your datas retrieve from the SQLite db.